# Nuxt add parameters without page and without reload the page

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I have a page with big list of data and some buttons for filtering.

for example 2 buttons to filter by status:

- Complete status
- Cancel status

I want when the user clicked on the complete the url to be changed to

http://demo.com/list?filter=complete

the page does not reloading, it just for get specific url foreach filter button.

How can I implement the code in Nuxt application?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? 
I would love to help

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `$route` or `$router` to change url, it set a new html5 history state and reload the page. So, to change url without reloading, history.replaceState do the job. In your page or component:

```
methods: {
   onClickComplete() {
      if (!process.server) { // I'm not sure it's necessary
         history.replaceState({}, null, window.location + '?filter=complete') // or use your own application logic: globalSiteUrl, $route... or queryString some vars...
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you should change your route with "$route.push" or click on 
these ways change the route without reloading

After than you can use "pages watchquery" to handle event of changing route
https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-watchquery/

Answer (score 1):

first create this helper function

```
export function getAbsoluteUrl(to) {
  const path = $nuxt.$router.resolve(to).href
  return window.location.origin + path
}
```

this is example for my tabs

```
  watch: {
    tab(value) {
      if (!process.server) {
        const url = getAbsoluteUrl({
          params: { ...this.$route.params, activeTab: value }
        })
        history.replaceState({}, null, url) // or use your own application logic: globalSiteUrl, $route... or queryString some vars...
      }
    }
  },
```